# Get highest value of JSON Python

Tags: python, json

Trying to get the highest value of a letter is kind of hard. When trying this, I get as a result the letter 'z'. How can I make it that it will return 'y' as the highest value?

Here's what I tried:

```
modes = {'x': 73, 'y': 2179, 'z': 173}
print(max(modes))
```

Result:

```
z
```

Comment: max is getting no information at all about the values in the dictionary, just the keys. Maybe read up on the key argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using the key argument:

```
 max(modes, key=lambda k: modes[k])
```